# How to use toast message inside Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am facing some problems when I'm using Toast inside run method of Thread class.

My error Logcat

```
09-16 11:42:38.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1446): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.monday.worker_android
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:75)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:244)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.monday.worker_android.SwipePage$2.doInBackground(SwipePage.java:142)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.monday.worker_android.SwipePage$2.doInBackground(SwipePage.java:1)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-16 11:59:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

But when I ignore Toast it works fine. But I want to use it. Please help.

Comment: You need to call it in UI thread.

Comment: Use handler to show toast in background thread.

Comment: consider using AsyncTask onPostExecute() method for showing Toast.

Comment: can you plz put your code?

Comment: Post your `doInBackground()` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use or access any UI elements inside a non UI thread. If you want to see some messages about your thread then you may use AsyncTask and use the UI stuffs inside preExecute method.because the pre and postExecute of AsyncTask are run on UI thread.

If you want to do like so then see [Problem with Toast in AsyncTask method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747645/problem-with-toast-in-asynctask-method-call) .

If you are excepting a small and easy way, then just use LOG class like:

```
Log.d("String Key", "the value you want to see");
```

If you want some ideas about log then please see [Android Log.v(), Log.d(), Log.i(), Log.w(), Log.e() - When to use each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959263/android-log-v-log-d-log-i-log-w-log-e-when-to-use-each-one)

Hope these are sufficient for your question.

Comment: I already give you some ways and links and also you can see the other answers here like jay ,pratic and sergi  to use runOnUiThread.All answers are helpful.

Answer (score 9):

By calling an Activity's **runOnUiThread** method from your Thread:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Toast message inside Thread", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You've to call the Toast on UI thread.

AsyncTask onPostExecute runs on UI thread. If you want to "force" a UI thread, you can use the following code inside onBackground:

```
// code runs in a thread
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
          public void run() {
              Toast.makeText(....).show();
          }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your `logcat` you are trying to update `UI part (using Toast)` in `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` *which is not possible directly*

Use same in `onPostExecute()` which is used for `handling/updating UI Part`

*If you want to show* `Toast in doInbackground()`
wrap the `Toast in runOnUIThread()` but this isn't the best solution.

*like*

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
          public void run() {
              // Show Toast Here
          }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may display your Toast message as below:

```
YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "This is Toast!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not print Toast in Thread, because Thread is running in background and it will not affect GUI things. You have to do it using UI Thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
          public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(this, "YOUR MESSAGE TO PRINT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show().
          }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call toast inside `onPostExecute()` method

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```